# selected=selected default value from database

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress website which I have installed a theme onto. This theme has a form which basically lets a user pick a location from a list of 'offices' and a date to pick up and drop off a vehicle. This customer only has one location to pick from. I have found the PHP code which pulls the 'location' data, and I believe I need to add the post ID into this for it to default to picking the only option which is available. This is the code below:

```
<h4><?php esc_html_e( 'Return', 'motors-wpbakery-widgets' ); ?></h4>
<div class="stm_rent_form_fields stm_rent_form_fields-drop">
    <div class="stm_same_return <?php echo ( 'on' === $fields['return_same'] ) ? '' : 'active'; ?>">
        <h4 class="stm_form_title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Place to drop the Car*', 'motors-wpbakery-widgets' ); ?></h4>
        <div class="stm_pickup_location stm_drop_location">
            <i class="stm-service-icon-pin"></i>
            <select name="drop_location" data-class="stm_rent_location">
                <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Choose office', 'motors-wpbakery-widgets' ); ?></option>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $locations ) ) : ?>
                   <?php foreach ( $locations as $location ) : ?>
                       <option
                            <?php echo ( $location[5] === $fields['return_location_id'] ) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
                            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $location[5] ); ?>">
                            <?php echo esc_html( $location[4] ); ?>
                        </option>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Post ID of the only 'location' available is post ID 107. Really hope someone can help and sorry if it's a bit vague at all! Thanks

I have logged into the backend, tried a few things I see off search engines, have small amounts of experience with tinkering with PHP but this is the furthest it has gone, so I'm slightly out of my depth (but want to learn!)

*edit* For reference, the website that I am currently building the website on is: http://envirovan2-co-uk.stackstaging.com/